# How do you send HTML formatted messages over XMPP with Node.JS?

Tags: html, node.js, xmpp

This question discusses sending messages with node-xmpp:
[Connecting to Google Talk over XMPP on Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349577/connecting-to-google-talk-over-xmpp-on-node-js)

Anyone know how to get an HTML formatted message.  The library they are using escapes the HTML in a node module called ltx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [XEP-0071](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0071.html).  Make sure your HTML is valid XML ([XHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML)), then embed like this:

```
<message>
  <body>Wow, I&apos;m green with envy!</body>
  <html xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im'>
    <body xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
      <p style='font-size:large'>
        <em>Wow</em>, I&apos;m <span style='color:green'>green</span>
        with <strong>envy</strong>!
      </p>
    </body>
  </html>
</message>
```

Note that the plain text is also included for clients that can't render XHTML.

Comment: We are using templates so we couldn't use the Element stuff because it kept escaping the templated HTML.