# Unable to connect to GTalk with node.js and node-xmpp

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmpp, google-talk, node-xmpp

I am trying to connect to GTalk using node.js and node-xmpp. Instead of successfully connecting, node-xmpp returns a XML error response.

### Preparation

```
$node -v
v0.10.24
$npm install node-stringprep
$npm install node-xmpp
$npm list
...
├─┬ node-xmpp@0.12.2
...
```

### gtalk.js

```
var xmpp = require('node-xmpp');
var sys = require("sys");

var options = {
    jid: "mygoogleid@gmail.com",
    password: "mygooglepassword"
    //,host: "talk.google.com"
    //,port: 5222
};

var jabber = new xmpp.Client(options);

jabber.on('online', function() {
    console.log("Connected");
});

jabber.on('error', function(e) {
    sys.puts(e);
});
```

### Error

```
$node gtalk.js
<stream:error xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams"><invalid-xml xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams"/></stream:error>
```

### Possible explanations

1. <del>**ID/password is wrong** (login at google website does works)</del>
2. <del>**node-xmpp needs host/port to connect to GTalk** (tried talk.google.com/5222)</del>
3. <del>**talk.google.com@5222** is wrong ([Google Doc Open Com](https://developers.google.com/talk/open_communications?csw=1) says it's correct)</del>
4. <del>**GTalk only allows OAuth2** ([Google Doc Open Com](https://developers.google.com/talk/open_communications?csw=1) says SASL PLAIN is allowed for "legacy" devices)</del>
5. <del>**This is the same as [StackOverflow#4349577](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349577/connecting-to-google-talk-over-xmpp-on-node-js)** (does not have same typo)</del>
6. <del>**I am using node-xmpp wrong**</del>
7. <del>**GTalk does not respond as expected**</del>
8. **node-xmpp is buggy<del>/does not support GTalk</del>**

I am pretty sure to have 1-5 ruled out and I would be glad to hear other explanations or evidence for 6-8. Thanks!

### Updates

**1. XML Stream ("=>" outbound, "<=" inbound)**

```
=> <stream:stream xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" version="1.0" to="gmail.com">
<= <stream:stream from="gmail.com" id="C2AA8A4648B596A1" version="1.0" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client"><stream:features><starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"><required/></starttls><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>X-OAUTH2</mechanism><mechanism>X-GOOGLE-TOKEN</mechanism></mechanisms></stream:features>
=> <starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>
<= <proceed xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>
=> <stream:stream xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" version="1.0" to="gmail.com">
<= <stream:stream from="gmail.com" id="3D42C6DC5985A9E6" version="1.0" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client">
<= <stream:features><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>X-OAUTH2</mechanism><mechanism>X-GOOGLE-TOKEN</mechanism><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism></mechanisms></stream:features>
=> <auth auth:service="oauth2" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl" mechanism="X-OAUTH2">AGNvaW2iaXRzeUBnbWFpbC5jb12AdW5kZWZpbmVk</auth>
<= <stream:error><invalid-xml xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams"/></stream:error>
```

It seems node-xmpp tries to use OAUTH2 although I haven't provided any token whatsoever. It should use PLAIN instead.

**2. node-xmpp oauth example doesn't work either**

Created OAUTH2 token according to node-xmpp pull request #85

```
$node node_modules/node_xmpp/examples/echo_bot_oauth.js gmailid@gmail.com oauth2token
No usable SASL mechanism
```

**3. Adding `preferred:"PLAIN"` fixes connection issue**

changing options to

```
 var options = {
   jid: "mygoogleid@gmail.com",
   password: "mygooglepassword",
   preferred: "PLAIN"
 };
```

fixes the error and seems to authenticate successfully. This might be evidence for explanation #8 (bug within node-xmpp).

Comment: The error suggests that you're sending syntactically invalid XML somehow.  Could you get hold of what's actually being sent to the server?  Not sure how to do that with node-xmpp, but tcpdump or Wireshark might help.

Comment: Updated captured XML stream, looks like node-xmpp tries to authenticate with oauth2, but GTalk doesn't like it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in node-xmpp introduced in 0.10.9.

- Issue has been filed
  (https://github.com/node-xmpp/node-xmpp-client/issues/21)
- Pull-request has been created
  (https://github.com/node-xmpp/node-xmpp-client/pull/22)
- Pull-request has been merged.

Answer (score 0):

The XML you send is indeed invalid:

```xml
<auth auth:service="oauth2"
      xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"
      mechanism="X-OAUTH2">
  ...
</auth>
```

It's using the `auth` namespace prefix without defining it anywhere.

[Google's description of OAuth authorization](https://developers.google.com/talk/jep_extensions/oauth) has an example that includes a namespace declaration (the `xmlns:auth` attribute):

```xml
<auth xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"
    mechanism="X-OAUTH2"
    auth:service="oauth2"
    xmlns:auth="http://www.google.com/talk/protocol/auth">
  base64("\0" + user_name + "\0" + oauth_token)
</auth>
```

So this should probably be reported as a bug to the node-xmpp developers.

Comment: `xmlns:auth` is indeed missing; however it shouldn't use OAuth2 in the first place. No idea how the token it uses has been generated. So it points to explanation #8 and I should file a bug report?

Comment: There should be an option to make it prefer `PLAIN` authentication, though I couldn't find any through a quick Google search.